# middelware GetX Flutter is not working with me

Tags: flutter, middleware, flutter-getx

i have Middelware with GetX in flutter but its not wrorking with me i dont know what is the issue

this is my Main file

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gettest/middelware/auth_middelware.dart';
import 'package:gettest/utiliz/mybindings.dart';
import 'package:gettest/view/adminpage.dart';
import 'package:gettest/view/counterpage.dart';
import 'package:gettest/view/home.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:gettest/view/login.dart';
import 'package:gettest/view/mirrorpage.dart';
import 'package:gettest/view/operationpage.dart';
import 'package:gettest/view/pageone.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

late SharedPreferences sharedpref;

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  sharedpref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues({});

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      home: LoginPage(),
      getPages: [
        GetPage(
            name: '/',
            page: () => LoginPage(),
            middlewares: [AuthMiddelware()]),
        GetPage(
          name: '/homepgae',
          page: () => HomePage(),
        ),
        GetPage(name: '/adminPage', page: () => const AdminPage()),
        GetPage(name: "/pageone", page: () => const PageOne()),
        GetPage(
            name: "/PageCounter",
            page: () => CounterPage(),
            binding: MyBinding()),
        GetPage(name: '/Pageoperation', page: () => const OperationPage()),
        GetPage(
            name: '/PageCounterMirror',
            page: () => MirorPage(),
            binding: MyBinding())
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

and this is my authMiddelware  File

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:gettest/main.dart';

class AuthMiddelware extends GetMiddleware {
  @override
  RouteSettings? redirect(String? route) {
    if (sharedpref.getString('role') == 'user') {
      return const RouteSettings(name: '/homepgae');
    }
    if (sharedpref.getString('role') == 'admin') {
      return const RouteSettings(name: '/adminPage');
    }
  }
}
```

and this is sig in  where is from the button should store from the sharedpreffrence and save on AuthMiddelware

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/placeholder.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:gettest/main.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const LoginPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('HtSouq'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {
                sharedpref.setString('role', 'users');
                Get.offNamed('/homepgae');
              },
              color: Colors.amberAccent,
              child: Text('Login'),
            ),
            MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {
                sharedpref.setString('role', 'admin');
                Get.offNamed('/adminPage');
              },
              color: Colors.amberAccent,
              child: Text('Admin'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

still the page will not get save  as the middleware is not working somebody can help on this

i run middleware to route me to the home if i am sign in already and save even if i restart the page  but still the rout will direct me to the first page with will ask me to sign in again

Answer (score 0):

Try using like this:

```
 @override
  RouteSettings? redirect(String? route) {
    if (sharedpref.getString('role') == 'user') {
      return const RouteSettings(name: '/homepgae');
    }
    if (sharedpref.getString('role') == 'admin') {
      return const RouteSettings(name: '/adminPage');
    }
    return null;
  }
```

if this returns null, the navigation is stopped, and no new routes are pushed.